# How to save to a "virtual local drive" and have the data streamed to a remote drive?

Tags: windows, cloud, files, filestream

(This is for Windows computers.)

So, the reason why I need this is not really important, but generally speaking...

I have a program which takes a long time to generate a huge file (like 100's of GB).

1. I don't have enough space to save that file locally.
2. I don't want to waste time generating the file and then waiting until that's done before I start sending it across the internet to another computer.

I would expect that there exists some utility program which installs like a local virtual drive, and when you save to it, it STREAMS the data to the actual physical drive. I don't want to have the destination drive be some place in the cloud. I want it to be a drive on another one of my computers which is in another place. So, both computers, (the source & destination), would almost certainly have to connect to some intermediate location in the cloud to do the streaming. I've heard of Google Drive File Stream, but I'm not sure if that works like I want. I don't want any intermediate piling up of data. I want the data to just stream across the internet from source to destination.

These 2 computers are not on the same local network or active directory or anything like that. They are totally separate, but on the Internet, behind firewalls, and I can't open them to externally initiated connections, like a VPN.

Also, I can't generate the file in chunks.

Answer (score 2):

Networking is the way to go here. Share a folder on the destination computer, mount it on the source computer and have the program write to it.

> These 2 computers are not on the same local network or active directory
> or anything like that. They are totally separate, but on the Internet,
> behind firewalls.

There are lots of way to bypass this, from opening ports in the firewalls to setting up a VPN.